# Passing json arguments to a spider in scrapy

Tags: json, scrapy, parameter-passing, scrapyd

I should pass to a spider some parameters taken from a json file. I have read that it is possible through scrapyd using schedule.json but I don't understand how to pass the json file. Someone of you have any experience?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't pass the arguments using a JSON file. Scrapyd has a JSON API where you can pass arguments along with it. (e.g. `$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider -d myargument="value"`)

You can handle the arguments passed through `kwargs`:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'somespider'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.myargument = kwargs.get('myargument', '')
```

See http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html for more info.

Comment: I have seen it but I don't understand where to pass the json file as argument of the spider

Comment: You can't pass a file per se. Closest thing you could do is pass the path of the file. (e.g. `-d /path/to/file`) and have your spider handle that somewhere in its code.

Comment: If I'm hosting my scrapyd instance on an AWS EC2 linux instance and I **needed** to pass a json file, how would I go about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284726/input-output-for-scrapyd-instance-hosted-on-an-amazon-ec2-linux-instance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question(I wanted to pass a json file to the spiders to implement a simple distributed crawl system.

And I simply solved it by converting the json file to a string as a argument in scrapyd.