# input/output for scrapyd instance hosted on an Amazon EC2 linux instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

Recently I began working on building web scrapers using scrapy. Originally I had deployed my scrapy projects locally using scrapyd.

The scrapy project I built relies on accessing data from a CSV file in order to run

```
 def search(self, response):
    with open('data.csv', 'rb') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        for row in reader:
            subscriberID = row[0]
            newEffDate = datetime.datetime.now()
            counter = 0
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url = "https://www.healthnet.com/portal/provider/protected/patient/results.action?__checkbox_viewCCDocs=true&subscriberId=" + subscriberID + "&formulary=formulary",
                callback = self.find_term,
                meta = {
                    'ID': subscriberID,
                    'newDate': newEffDate,
                    'counter' : counter
                    }
                )
```

It outputs scraped data to another CSV file

```
 for x in data:
        with open('missing.csv', 'ab') as fout:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = ',')
            csvwriter.writerow([oldEffDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),subscriberID,ipa])
            return
```

We are in the initial stages of building an application that needs to access and run these scrapy spiders. I decided to host my scrapyd instance on an AWS EC2 linux instance. Deploying to AWS was straightforward (http://bgrva.github.io/blog/2014/04/13/deploy-crawler-to-ec2-with-scrapyd/).

**How do I input/output scraped data to/from a scrapyd instance running on an AWS EC2 linux instance?**

EDIT:
I'm assuming passing a file would look like

```
curl http://my-ec2.amazonaws.com:6800/schedule.json -d project=projectX -d spider=spider2b -d in=file_path
```

Is this correct? How would I grab the output from this spider run? Does this approach have security issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is S3 an option? I'm asking because you're already using EC2. If that's the case, you could read/write from/to S3.

I'm a bit confused because you mentioned both CSV and JSON formats. If you're reading CSV, you could use [CSVFeedSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#csvfeedspider). Either way, you could also use [boto](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) to read from S3 in your spider's `__init__` or `start_requests` method.

Regarding the output, [this page](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#s3) explains how to use feed exports to write the output of a crawl to S3.

Relevant settings:

- [FEED_URI](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_URI)
- [FEED_FORMAT](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-format)
- [AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
- [AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#aws-secret-access-key)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I edited my question to make it less confusing